# “...than they have” or “...than they have done”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality-in-context, ellipsis, do-support

The source: SIMON & Schuster Handbook for writers

When I was reading this book, I came across this sentence.

> - We live in an age when people do more writing than they **have** at any other time in history.

Why it appears awkward to me :

And the right one sounds like:

....than they have **done** at...

Comment: **than they have,  than they've done, than they have done** are all grammatical.  The verb DO  (in its past participle form) is there *in absentia*, as it were, after the auxiliary.    *I have seen more cars with one headlight tonight than I have in a year!*  *I see more cars with one headlight these days than I ever have!*

Comment: the "done" can be omitted.  Such omissions are fairly common in English, but less so in other languages - so that might be why you think it is odd.

Comment: The lexical verb of the main clause is carried over implicitly into the *than*-clause. It is a comparison, so the terms of the comparison are understood to be like-vs-like.  The listener unconsciously supplies [seen] not **owned**, say, in my headlight examples, because that is the lexical verb of the main clause.  Two acts of seeing are being compared.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - exactly, the word "done" is seen to be there, although it isn't actually there. Thanks for the technical lingo!

Comment: I'm only a dabbler in the technical lingo. Others here are much more in command of it than I am.  They would find my use of the phrase *than*-clause quite parochial :)

Comment: But I should add that I have spent a long time studying English in school, including five years in graduate school, however my focus was philological, diachronic, not generative.

Comment: Both of these are correct. 'Done' is not necessary.

Comment: Edited the title as "at" is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It is called ellipsis, basically when words are omitted from a sentence or language because they can be understood, or are implied by context or syntax. It's probably a good thing that it sounds a bit awkward to you because that means you can see that something is missing, and there is nothing wrong with including *done* in your sentence. Using ellipsis is not a requirement of English but it does help to avoid repetition, which is probably how it developed in the first place. Tᴚoɯɐuo is really onto it in his comments and he may have something to add the question of how it developed.

see here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)

Answer (score 1):

It is correct as it is. But, it feels awkward because there is a "do" in the first part but no "do" in the second part. It's a "missing top step."

> We live in an age when people **do** more writing than they have **(missing do)** at any other time in history.

People are do-ing in the first part of the comparison, but have-ing in the second part. It's awkward but correct.

I suspect the person who wrote that sentence is trying to emphasize a particular kind of writing. Thus they want to say that a person is to "do writing" rather than just write. Maybe they want to emphasize literature as opposed to jam-jar labels.

So the awkwardness has crept in under cover of this motivation. Don't have people "do writing." Just have them write.

> We live in an age when people write more than they have at any other time in history.

Answer (score 1):

"To avoid repetition [of the main verb]

We use auxiliary verbs to avoid repeating the same verb or verb phrase in a sentence.

If the first part contains an auxiliary verb, we use the same verb in the second part.

I don’t like going to spas, but my wife does.
I thought I had lost my keys, but I hadn’t.
Tom can play the guitar and Tina can’t.
She has never had to face such difficulties, but I have.
If the first part doesn’t contain an auxiliary verb, we use do or did in the second part.

She shares your opinion, but I don’t.
Some wanted to go on with the plan, but others didn’t."

[use of auxiliary verbs](https://test-english.com/explanation/b1-2/auxiliary-verbs-different-uses/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you a British English speaker? There are differences between American and British English when it comes to ellipsis and *do*-support.

[This page](https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2007/09/pro-predicate-do-and-verb-phrase.html) gives the examples:

> (1) I ate all the chocolate, even though I shouldn't have done.
> (2) I ate all the chocolate, even though I shouldn't have.

Sentences like (1) occur in British English, but would sound odd in American English, where (2) is preferred.

Now we can change the sentences to use a comparative construction (as in the question).

> (1') I ate more chocolate than I should have done. [BrE]
> (2') I ate more chocolate than I should have. [AmE]

Note that *done* in (1) and (1') is referring to the main verb of the first part of the sentence, *ate*. This is a special function of *do* known as [*do*-support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support) (also seen in sentences like "I ate chocolate and so **did** you").

An alternative to *do*-support is to repeat the first verb outright. This is fine even in American English:

> (3') I ate more chocolate than I should have eaten.

Now going back to the sentence in the question:

> people do more writing than they have at any other time in history

This has a structure like (2'), which is fine in American English. The main verb here is actually *do*, so it is also fine to say

> people do more writing than they have **done** at any other time in history

even in American English. The structure is similar to (3'). Or, in British English, this could be interpreted as *do*-support, like in (1').

Comment: Note: I am an American English speaker. I could be wrong about (1') for British English.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to add the word 'done' here, it's just like the usual way of avoiding repeating word (here we mean 'verb'). The phrase 'at any other time in history' is a common one, people wouldn't mess it up with the former phrase 'they have'.